# Why prop is undefined in child component Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component where I want to pass `[size]` of SVG image

```
<app-svg-icon [size]="{ width: 40, height: 40 }" name="{{menuItem.icon}}_green">
```

When I check the `[size]` in `app-svg-icon`, the size is `undefined`, when I pass without property binding [], I receive only string `'{width: 40, height: 40}'`, when I try to pass as interpolation `size="{{size}}"` (size as var in component) it is returned as `[Object, Object]`

```
  @Input() size?: {
        width?: number;
        height?: number;
      };
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.size, typeof this.size) // undefined
  }
```

Please help

**UPD 1**

Both answers below were correct, I haven't provided the full info. The variable was undefined only in `svgElementFromString()` and available in `ngOnit`:

```
@Input()
  set name(iconName: string) {
    if (this.svgIcon) this.element.nativeElement.removeChild(this.svgIcon);
    const svgData = this.iconRegistryService.getIcon(iconName);
    this.svgIcon = this.svgElementFromString(svgData);
    this.element.nativeElement.appendChild(this.svgIcon);
  }
         @Input() size?: {
        width?: number;
        height?: number;
      };
    
      constructor(private element: ElementRef, private iconRegistryService: IconRegistryService, @Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }
    
      private svgElementFromString(svgContent: string): SVGElement {
        const div = this.document.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = svgContent;
        console.log(this.size) // undefined
        // if (this.size?.width) div.style.width = this.size.width + 'px';
        // if (this.size?.height) div.style.height = this.size.height + 'px';
        return div.querySelector('svg') || this.document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.size, typeof this.size) // I can see the siz
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Variable in controller

If you have a variable in the controller holding the object like below

**Parent controller**

```js
export const ParentComponent {
  size = { width: 40, height: 40 };
  ...
}
```

you could then use the data-binding using square brackets and pass the object.

```html
<app-svg-icon [size]="size" name="{{menuItem.icon}}_green">
```

#### Option 2: No variable in controller

If you wish to bind the object directly in the template you could do so without using the square brackets and parse the string using a setter in the child.

**Parent template**

```html
<app-svg-icon size='{ "width": 40, "height": 40 }' name="{{menuItem.icon}}_green">
```

Note: The type of quotes could not be matched. In case of error try to use the quotes exactly as shown here.

**Child controller**

```js
export const SvgIcon implements OnInit {
  _size?: { width?: number; height?: number };

  @Input() set size(dims: any) {
    this._size = typeof dims === "object" ? dims : JSON.parse(dims);
  }

  get size() {
    return this._size;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.size, typeof this.size);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of sending data directly just use a function

**Parent.html**

```
<app-svg-icon [size]="getSize()" name="{{menuItem.icon}}_green">
```

**Parent.ts**

```
getSize() {
    return this.size = 
 {
    width : 40,
    height: 40
 };

}
```